How do I add multiple enchantments through commands onto a stick in Minecraft Java edition 1.20.4 Fabric Loader?
I used this command: /give SweatyPearz stick{ench:[{id:19,lvl:100},{id:16,lvl:100},{id:20,lvl:101}]} and it gave me a normal stick that doesn't do anything special.
Did I use the command wrong, is it because I'm using Fabric Loader or is it something else? I tried using chat and command blocks but it didn't work.

Possible duplicate of How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons

Command format changed in 1.13. I would assume you are using outdated material.
The ench tag has been replaced with Enchantments, and as far as I'm aware, id no longer accept numerical ids (only string ids).
For example, your command can be changed to this:
/give SweatyPearz stick{Enchantments:[{id:knockback,lvl:100},{id:sharpness,lvl:100},{id:fire_aspect,lvl:101}]}

You can see more usages of the /give command on the Minecraft Wiki (Note: Revision is from before 1.20.5).

And before anyone brings up components, OP said 1.20.4.
